# How to reverse a LinkedList from a certain index, given the code fragments below

Tags: java, linked-list

I would like to write a method `public void reverseFrom(int index)` which reverses a list *from* the given index.

I would like to ***only*** use the  `LinkedList` class below.

```
public class LinkedList {

    public Node head = null;

    public class Node {
        public int value;
        public Node next;

        Node(int value, Node next) {
            this.value = value
            this.next = next;
        }
    }
}
```

I have a method to reverse a LinkedList:

```
public void reverse() {
    Node tmp = head;
    Node prev = null;
    Node nextNode = null;

    while(tmp != null) {
        nextNode = tmp.next;
        tmp.next = prev;
        prev = tmp;
        tmp = nextNode;
    }
    head = prev;
}
```

So far, for the `reverseFrom` method, I have:

```
public void reverseFrom(int index) {
    if(index == 0) {
        reverse();
    } else if (index == 1) {
        return;
    } else {
        Node tmp = head;
        for(int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
            tmp = tmp.next;
        }
        Node newHead = tmp;
        /*** Node prev = null;
        Node nextNode = null;
        while(newHead != null) {
            nextNode = newHead.next;
            newHead.next = prev;
            prev = newHead;
            newHead = nextNode;
        }
        newHead = prev; ***/
    }
}
```

I have tried using the code from `reverse()` but it does not work (that which is commented out).
How can I then reverse the list from `newHead`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could base the logic on the `reverse` method, but use an extra reference to the node that is at `index - 1`. During the loop decrement `index`. As long as it is positive, don't change the `next` reference of the current node. When it hits zero, take note of where we start the reversal, and as the current node will become the very last one, set its `next` reference to `null`. When `index` is negative, perform the usual reversal logic.

After the loop, check whether we need to change the `head` or whether we need to attach the reversed part to the node at `index-1`:

```
public void reverseFrom(int index) {
    Node tmp = head;
    Node prev = null;
    Node nextNode = null;
    Node tail = null; // node at index - 1

    while (tmp != null) {
        nextNode = tmp.next;
        if (index == 0) {
            // We arrived at the part that needs reversal
            tmp.next = null;
            tail = prev;
        } else if (index < 0) {
            // Perform normal reversal logic
            tmp.next = prev;
        }
        index--;
        prev = tmp;
        tmp = nextNode;
    }
    if (tail == null) {
        head = prev;
    } else {
        tail.next = prev;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class ReverseList<T> extends LinkedList<T>{
    public void reverseFrom(int idx) {
        if (idx < 0 || idx > size()) {
            return;
        }
        
        Stack<T> stack = new Stack<T>();
        while (idx < size()) {
            stack.push(remove(idx));
        }
        
        while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
            add(stack.pop());
        }
    }
    /******* Alternative slution ***************/
 public void reverseFrom(int idx) {
    if (idx < 0 || idx > size()) {
        return;
    }
    
    reverseFromInternal(idx, size()-1);
}

private void reverseFromInternal(int a, int b) {
    if (a >= b) {
        return;
    }
    T far = remove(b);
    T near = remove(a);
    
    add(a, far);
    add(b, near);
    
    reverseFromInternal(a + 1, b - 1);
}
 /****************************************/
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        ReverseList<String> list = new ReverseList<>();
        
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            list.add(Integer.toString(i));
        }
        list.reverseFrom(5);
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you but I would like to do this using only the LinkedList class that I have provided in the question.

Comment: The logic would be the same. Remove items from the list starting at the index, place them in a FILO collection then empty the FILO collection to your list.

Comment: Alternatively, you could make a recursive function that swaps from idx to size() -1 and just increment the and decrement the parameters until the first value is >= the second value

Answer (score 1):

```
    public void reverseFrom(int index) {
        if (index == 0) {
            reverse();

            return;
        }

        Node tmp = head;
        Node previous = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
            previous = tmp;
            tmp = tmp.next;
        }
        Node newHead = tmp;

        LinkedList subLinkedList = new LinkedList();
        subLinkedList.head = newHead;
        subLinkedList.reverse();

        previous.next = subLinkedList.head;
    }
```

Comment: With this method I only get the elements in the list up to the `newHead`

Comment: @h4ckerlinguist true, I have reworked the solutions and from now it works properly